# Why's my wheel spinning repugnantly when clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging

I'd like to know why the wheel spins like a bent bicycle tire when clicking Spin Now.  I've tried a lot of ways to try to rectify this so that it spins normally like the Wheel of Fortune wheel but to no avail.

I tried switching up the image, give it a height and width, slow down the wheel but nothing seems to be working and it feels like I'm running out of options

I think my jQuery code is a bit off and is causing this inconsistent behavior but I could be wrong.  How can make the wheel spin normally?  A JsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/hbxL2s8r/26/) and code below is provided for reference.

Here's HTML:

```
<div id="spin-now" class="buttons">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/28JSM5Kf/spin-now-glow-button-NEW.png" alt="">
</div>

<div id="image-spinner" class="text-center">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nzZz2wwj/wheel-no-glow-v03.png"/>
</div>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
var degrees = 0, previousRotation = 0;

var spinNow = document.getElementById('spin-now');

spinNow.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log("triggered");
    $('#spin-now').hide();

    previousRotation = degrees;

    degrees += parseInt(360 * 10 + 315);

    // controls speed of wheel
    var milliseconds = parseInt((degrees - previousRotation)) * 1.5; 

    $("#image-spinner").css({
        "-webkit-transform" : "rotate("+ degrees +"deg)",
        "-webkit-transition-duration" : milliseconds + "ms"
    });
});
```

Comment: clearly your centre of rotation isn't where you want it to be ... adding `#image-spinner { display:inline-block }` will fix it - either that or spin the image not the div

Comment: @JaromandaX tried both of your suggestions but it didn't work :(

Comment: really? https://jsfiddle.net/vLcdw981/